# Firebase Admin update function calling multiple callbacks in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I know for a fact that reading data from firebase with firebase admin returns multiple callbacks. that is why I use ref.once(), like example below:

```
const ref = db.ref('clients');
ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  res.send(snapshot.val());
}, (errorObject) => {
  console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
});
```

But, when I try to update data I get into the same trouble of receiving multiple callbacks crashing my application, but I can't use once in ref.update, what can I do to prevent receiving multiple callbacks?

```
app.get('/set-client', (req, res) => {

  const ref = db.ref(`users/new_users`)
  
  ref.update({ 'client': uid_client}).then(function(){
    console.log("Data saved successfully.");
    res.status(200).send("successful")
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
    res.status(201).send("failed")
  });
});
```

Here is a code example.

Comment: Are you saying that you get the console.log you have written gets printed more than once?

Comment: it calls the .then(function()) more than once, and as consequence, it tries to send res.status(200) two times, and crashes with this error:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)

Comment: Try investing by adding a parameter in .then(function()). So it becomes .then(function(param)) and console param. See what you get.

Comment: You know what the fun part is? yesterday I just wasted the whole day trying to debug it, I didn't change a dime in my code, and Trying to reproduce the error now just didn't return an error. This firebase just drives me crazy, I'll try to test later. So I won't close the question for now

Answer (score 2):

When interacting with responses in the way you've shown, you might find that using the `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` variant of the `then()` method may be of use.

**Quick note**: When using this approach, care must be taken to understand that if the `onFulfilled` handler throws an exception/rejects, the sibling `onRejected` handler will **not** be called with its exception. The exception is instead passed onto the next chained `onRejected` handler in later `then`/`catch` calls. The sibling will only catch exceptions/rejections from steps prior to it in the chain.

Here is an example of the difference:

```
const somePromise = /* ... */;

const resultPromise = somePromise
  .then((data) => { /* handle data */ })   // an error thrown here
  .catch((err) => { /* handle error */ })  // gets caught here

// vs.

const resultPromise = somePromise
  .then(
    (data) => { /* handle data */ },  // an error thrown here, will reject resultPromise
    (err) => { /* handle error */ }   // instead of being handled here
  )
```

This trait of the `onRejected` handler in `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` can be applied in a way where headers can't be sent twice for the same response. If for whatever reason the `onFulfilled` handler throws an exception while trying to send a response, the `onRejected` handler that is also responsible for sending a response is skipped - preventing any headers already sent errors.

This means that the first code block gets swapped out for:

```
const ref = db.ref('clients');
ref.once('value')
  .then(
    (snapshot) => { // got data successfully
      console.log('got data successfully');
      // don't forget to check snapshot.exists() if data could be missing
      res.send(snapshot.val()); // using .json() over .send() is recommended for arbitrary data
    },
    (error) => { // failed to get data/permission
      console.error('Failed to read data at /clients: ', error);
      res.status(500).send('Data unavailable.');
    }
  )
  .catch(
    (error) => { // if here, either of the above blocks failed - probably due to an error related to the response.
      console.error('Failed to send response to client: ', error);
      try { res.end() } catch (e) {} // forcefully terminate connection if not already
    }
  );
```

and the second code block for:

```
app.get('/set-client', (req, res) => {
  const ref = db.ref(`users/new_users`)
  
  ref.update({ 'client': uid_client }) // uid_client is undefined?
    .then(
      () => {
        console.log("Data updated successfully.");
        res.status(200).send("successful");
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Data could not be saved.", error);
        res.status(500).send("failed"); // don't use HTTP 201 Created here
      }
    )
    .catch(
      (error) => { // if here, either of the above blocks failed - probably due to an error related to the response.
        console.error('Failed to send response to client: ', error);
        try { res.end() } catch (e) {} // forcefully terminate connection if not already
      }
    );
});
```

The error handler that logs response errors could be rewritten so that it can be reused by taking in the relevant response object (so it can terminated when needed) and returning the error handler:

```
const buildResponseErrorHandler = (response) => ((error) => {
  console.error('Failed to send response to client: ', error);
  try { response.end() } catch (e) {} // forcefully terminate connection if not already
});

// usage:
somePromise
  .then(
    sendResponseHandlerForSuccess,
    sendResponseHandlerForFailure
  )
  .catch(buildResponseErrorHandler(res)) // buildResponseErrorHandler(res) returns (err) => { /* logs problem */ }
```

Comment: Lemme see If I got this right, In the way I was doing, I wasn't capable to catch the error related to the response, only to the firebase database, and that is why my app was crashing?

Comment: @JulioLopes Something in your `then` handler threw an exception - could be a handful of different things (a syntax error, invalid data, `undefined` values, etc.). When this happened, your `catch` handler tried to send a response to the client - but because the `then` handler already sent the headers, this caused another new exception. This new exception caused the promise to reject once again, which wasn't handled by your code, which crashed the whole app. This answer covered a way to prevent ending up in such a situation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, helped-me a lot, I got stuck in this for 2 days. 

I'm new here, so, if you don't mind anshwering another question. What makes a question worthy of a thumbs up? I'm having difficulties in getting reputation on my questions...

Comment: @CesarLopes No idea as my questions aren't upvoted much either. 99% of my reputation is built on bounties and answers. In my own experience, questions are upvoted a lot by "I have this problem too" readers. Outside of that, everything comes down to question quality - something highly regarded here on StackOverflow. I personally tend to upvote well phrased (& searchable) questions that are presented nicely, tagged appropriately, include all necessary information (linking to docs as needed) with evidence of their own research and are of sufficient quality to be used as targets for duplicates.